# Process execution check and getting PID in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, subprocess, popen, pid

I need to run a bash command in the background but then need to kill(os.kill()) it later. I also want to make Sure the command runs I have this to make sure the command runs.

```
if subprocess.Popen("tcpdump -i eth0 -XX -w /tmp/tmp.cap &", shell=True).wait() == 0:
```

I'm not sure on how to change this so i can use Popen.pid to get the pid while still being able to check if execution was successful.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: you can use a variable `p = Popen(...)`, `p.kill()` -- to kill, `returncode = p.wait()` - to wait for completion. btw, you don't need `shell=True` here: drop `shell=True` and `&` at the end and use `p = Popen(shlex.split(cmd))`

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure if I need shell=True or & but it worked with them, I will try what you've advised, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start a subprocess, wait some time and kill it, and check that its exit status is zero:

```
import shlex
from subprocess import Popen
from threading import Timer

def kill(process):
    try:
        process.kill()
    except OSError: 
        pass # ignore

p = Popen(shlex.split("tcpdump -i eth0 -XX -w /tmp/tmp.cat"))
t = Timer(10, kill, [p]) # run kill in 10 seconds
t.start()
returncode = p.wait()
t.cancel()
if returncode != 0:
   # ...
```

Or you could implement the timeout yourself:

```
import shlex
from subprocess import Popen
from time import sleep, time as timer # use time.monotonic instead

p = Popen(shlex.split("tcpdump -i eth0 -XX -w /tmp/tmp.cat"))

deadline = timer() + 10 # kill in 10 seconds if not complete
while timer() < deadline:
    if p.poll() is not None: # process has finished
        break 
    sleep(1) # sleep a second
else: # timeout happened
    try:
        p.kill()
    except OSError:
        pass

if p.wait() != 0:
   # ...
```

It assumes `sleep` uses similar clock as `timer`.

`threading.Timer` variant allows your code to continue as soon as the subprocess exits.

Comment: `Popen.wait()` does not allow the process to "run in the background", as requested by the OP.

Comment: @Graham: `.wait()` is called only after the process *already* has finished (in the second example) or been killed. In both cases the process doesn't survive after 10 seconds. "background" is the term from the shell. There is no shell here. `Popen` runs all processes in "background" unless you mean that you want to create a unix daemon process (it is unlikely that OP needs it)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Popen.poll()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) method. You can get the `Popen.returncode` as well to determine if the processes completed successfully.

```
import subprocess

tasks = [subprocess.Popen('ping www.stackoverflow.com -n 5 && exit 0', shell=True),
         subprocess.Popen('ping www.stackoverflow.com -n 5 && exit 1', shell=True)]

for task in tasks:
    while task.poll() is None:
        # the task has not finished
        pass

    print task
    print task.pid
    print task.returncode
```

Comment: OP starts *single* process. `task.returncode` check is redundant. `not task.poll()` is wrong: it should be `task.poll() is None` -- the process is still running. In general, busy loop should be avoided (you could pause between the checks).

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian, I understand that OP starts a single process, which is not `ping`... OP wanted to know the process terminated successfully, and the two example processes terminate with different exit codes in order to demonstrate that functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the Replies, I'm sorry if my question misled you, I want to check that the process executed successfully, but the process should keep running in the background until killed. As in if TCPDump wasn't installed it would fail to run and I would want to know that. Thanks for your replies.